# Partitions primary/logical

Tags: oracle-linux

I have two questions:

1. How one knows that this (any) disk partition should be a Primary partition or Logical? Please explain it if possible.
2. How am I suppose to know that how much size is to be allocated to each partition? Is there a fixed rule? If so what is it.

Comment: Release 5? Which distro? Different distributions have differing requirements. Please click on `edit` above and to the left and explain which distribution of Linux you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

Primary and secondary partitions are not Linux specific.

The original MBR partition table was defined to have room for 4 partitions. Back in the day, disks were around 10-40 MB. Yes, megabytes. So in most cases people created just one partition for the whole disk, and 4 partitions was enough for most. Eventually there was a desire to overcome this limitation, and the concept of an extended partition was introduced. Basically, the 4 partition entries would be called primary, while one of those 4 could be marked as extended. The extended partition is just a container for logical partitions. The format doesn't limit the number of logical partitions, although different systems may have different limits. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record).

Some operating systems require their boot partitions to be primary partitions. Standard boot loaders just load a boot record from one primary partition, the active partition. Linux boot loaders like Grub can boot from any partition.

Allocating space for partitions is a matter of preference and usage expectations. If you're unsure, just create one big partition for your file system, and a swap partition if you need swap.

Comment: Primary and extended/logical partitions are obsolete, and are replaced by the Guid Partition Table (GPT) scheme, where each partition is created equal. There is no reason to use the old DOS/MBR partition scheme on new computers anymore.

Comment: @JohanMyréen While that may be true, that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You have read into the question a restriction to the old MBR partitioning scheme that is not actually there.

Comment: @JdeBP Are you implying that GPT still has the distinction between primary and logical partitions?

Comment: @RalfFriedl I didn't pretend I answered the question. I just wrote a comment in the comments section. I just wanted to point out that you totally neglected the modern partitioning scheme (GPT).